# react useState enters infinite loop even thou variable is the same

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code:

```
  const [ ddFilterData, setddFilterData ] = useState('');



useEffect(() => {
      getDropdownData();
  }, [ddFilterData]);

const getDropdownData = async () => {
  if(optionDetails) {
    let filteredData = Promise.all(
      optionDetails.map(async (item, i) => {
          const fltData = await filterData(item, props.items);
          return fltData
        })
      )
      filteredData.then(returnedData => {
        setddFilterData(returnedData);
      })

  }

}
```

What I need is for useEffect to execute eah time ddFilerData changes with NEW or DIFFERENT data.
From my understanding it should only update or run when teh ddFilterData is different no?

Currently it runs on each change.  The code above enters into an infinite loop even thou filteredData isn't different.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are causing the infinite loop - each time the variable ddFilterData changes, you call getDropdownData, which updates ddFilterData, which calls getDropdownData, which updates ddFilterData and so on.

Comment: just put your `setddFilterData` somewhere else.not in your `getDropdownData` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `returnedData` is an array. So when you do `setddFilterData(returnedData)` you're setting a new value for `ddFilterData`. Because React uses [Object.is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is#Description) for comparison, even if the array elements are the same as previously, it is still a different object and will trigger `useEffect` again, causing the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

your `getDropdownData` method is updating `ddFilterData` which causes re-render. And on re-render you `getDropdownData` is called which updated `ddFilterData` due to this cyclic behavior your are getting infinte loop.

Modify your code like this:

```
  const [ ddFilterData, setddFilterData ] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  getDropdownData();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
 // put your code here if you want to do something on change of ddFilterData
}, [getDropdownData]);


const getDropdownData = async () => {
  if(optionDetails) {
    let filteredData = Promise.all(
    optionDetails.map(async (item, i) => {
      const fltData = await filterData(item, props.items);
      return fltData
    })
  )
  filteredData.then(returnedData => {
    setddFilterData(returnedData);
  })

 }

}
```